# AngularJs ng-repeat only displaying first element

Tags: jquery, angularjs, arrays

I'm new to Angular, and I can't quite figure out why ng-repeat is only displaying the first element from my object.

Here is my **HTML**

```
<div ng-app="GroupApp">
 <div ng-controller="GroupCtrl">
<div id="divEditRow" class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8" ng-repeat="data in editGroups track by $index">
          <div   class="input-group input-group-lg" >
              <input class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="data[$index].GroupName" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </span>

           </div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my angularjs:

```
var app = angular
       .module('GroupApp', [])
       .controller('GroupCtrl', function ($scope, AddGroup, $http) {
           var id_generator = function (id) {
               return id + 1
           }
           $scope.groups = [{ 'id': 1, 'name': '' }];
         //  $scope.editGroups = new Array();
           $http.get("/Group/GetGroups")
              .success(function (data) {
                  $scope.editGroups = data;
              });
 })
```

I know the data is being retrieved correctly b/c when writing {{ data }} to the screen, the following is returned:

```
[{"CompetencyGroupID":52,"GroupName":"Quality Control","CreateDateTime":"/Date(1470675542267)/","CreateUserId":137,"ModifiedDateTime":null,"ModifiedUserID":null},{"CompetencyGroupID":53,"GroupName":"Quality","CreateDateTime":"/Date(1470675715943)/","CreateUserId":137,"ModifiedDateTime":null,"ModifiedUserID":null},{"CompetencyGroupID":54,"GroupName":"adsf","CreateDateTime":"/Date(1470681237727)/","CreateUserId":137,"ModifiedDateTime":null,"ModifiedUserID":null}]
```

This is my C# Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetGroups()
    {
        List<CompetencyGroup> groupList = new List<CompetencyGroup>();

        using (var db = new SSITrainingEntities())
        {
            //return (from g in db.CompetencyGroups
            //        select g).ToList();
            groupList = db.CompetencyGroups.ToList();
        }
        var j = Json(new { Response = groupList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return j;
        //return groupList;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ng-model="data[$index].GroupName" data is the model, you need to use on this way ng-model="data.GroupName".
Can you check that?

Comment: Yes, I tried this earlier, but it doesn't return anything - not even the first element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the data variable as the original array. The data variable is the actual element (object in this case) inside the editGroups array. You simply can access each object within the array using `data.PropertyName`.

> **Note**: I have removed the http call and directly used the data
>   provided.

```js
var app = angular
       .module('GroupApp', [])
       .controller('GroupCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
         var data = [{"CompetencyGroupID":52,"GroupName":"Quality Control","CreateDateTime":"/Date(1470675542267)/","CreateUserId":137,"ModifiedDateTime":null,"ModifiedUserID":null},{"CompetencyGroupID":53,"GroupName":"Quality","CreateDateTime":"/Date(1470675715943)/","CreateUserId":137,"ModifiedDateTime":null,"ModifiedUserID":null},{"CompetencyGroupID":54,"GroupName":"adsf","CreateDateTime":"/Date(1470681237727)/","CreateUserId":137,"ModifiedDateTime":null,"ModifiedUserID":null}];
           var id_generator = function (id) {
               return id + 1
           }
           $scope.groups = [{ 'id': 1, 'name': '' }];
         //  $scope.editGroups = new Array();
           $scope.editGroups = data;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="GroupApp">
 <div ng-controller="GroupCtrl">
<div id="divEditRow" class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8" ng-repeat="data in editGroups track by $index">
          <div   class="input-group input-group-lg" >
              <input class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="data.GroupName" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </span>

           </div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your C# API Controller method, it seems like you are passing in an object called response that contains the array of groups. You can either remove the new Object and directly pass in the groupList var as the first argument or change your success callback to access the `Response` property.

```
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.editGroups = data.Response;
});
```

Comment: yes that would certainly work, however, the data I'm retrieving is from my DB. It will not be hardcoded data.

Comment: I updated my question to include the c# controller I'm getting the data from.

Comment: If this answer does't solve your problem you should add here correct object structure. You can check your backend's response data with chrome's developer tools Network tab.

Comment: This was certainly part of the answer. My biggest issue was how I was returning my list to the client as JsonResult .So instead of using JsonResult type, I just serialized my list instead.